# Esper - Detect absence of a certain event with WHERE

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing

I was looking to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796373/esper-detect-absence-of-a-certain-event), i need this `select * from pattern [every (timer:interval(10 sec) and not EventX)];` but with a WHERE id = "001", i dont know where to put the WEHERE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from pattern [every (timer:interval(10 sec) and not EventX(id="001"))];
```